# What is this plastic piece included with the cradle cap sponge?

Tags: newborn, cleaning

I've gotten one of these cradle cap sponges with each of my children, and they have all come with that blue plastic piece. Does anyone have any idea what purpose it's meant to serve?

[image: Sponge and plastic piece]

Comment: I'm tickled by the idea that these "came with the children", like the babies were delivered in retail boxes from Amazon...

Comment: what brand is it?

Comment: No idea, unfortunately...packaging is long gone.

Comment: Looks like a mini measuring spoon. If you don't have the packaging any more, are you sure that was included with the sponge?

Comment: Confirmed with my wife that this was indeed in the same package as the sponge. I've googled and found several things that look like the sponge, but no pics ever include the plastic piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you google "surgical brush with nail cleaner" you will have your answer.  These brushes were designed for surgeons to clean their hands prior to surgery. They have been re-purposed for removing cradle cap, and the nail cleaner is just part of the package. They are designed for single use.

Comment: Indeed. Mystery solved. Thank you! Good to know I haven't been missing anything. (Or trying to somehow use a nail cleaner on my newborns scalp...)